# How can I write key-value pairs in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog, tuprolog

Imagine I have the following predicate, which states that the ID `loc1` designates a location.

```
isLocation('loc1', 'Location 1').
```

I want to provide translations for the second text (`Location 1`), i. e. key-value pairs such as `en='Location 1', de='Ort 1', ru='Местоположение 1'`.

What is the correct way to encode such data in Prolog, especially TuProlog (and ideally - standardized Prolog) ?

Would the notation below work outside SWI Prolog?

```
isLocation('loc1', ['en'-'Location 1', 'de'-'Ort 1', 'ru'-'Местоположение 1']]).
```

Comment: There is no need to use single quotes if the atom is also a valid atom without the quotes. Simply write such atoms down. as in `loc1`, `in`, `de` etc. Use GNU Prolog to see if your text is valid ISO syntax. SWI-Prolog is not ISO conformant and is not suitable for judging the validity of your Prolog syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest way, working in any Prolog, uses member/2 to retrieve key-value pairs. For instance

```
l10n(MessageId, Country, Translated) :-
  isLocation(MessageId, Localized),
  member(Country-Translated, Localized).
```

Such basic construct would need of course several improvements, depending on requirements.